# Better way to retry a statement that threw an exception in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, exception

I usually do something like this:

```
    Dim Attempts = 0
    Try
Retry:
        <Block>
    Catch
        If Attempts < 3 Then
            Attempts += 1
            Thread.Sleep(2000)
            GoTo Retry
        Else
            Throw
        End If
    End Try
```

This is really bad looking for me, but i don't know of a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's a bad usage, I use this one, and it's much cleaner.

```
Dim maxAttempt As Integer = 2

For i As Integer = maxAttempt To 0 Step -1

 Try
    ...
    'Successful Quit
    Exit For

  Catch
     Thread.Sleep(2000)

  End Try
Next
```

Comment: Be aware that you are silently catching all exceptions, even in the last try where the exception should be passed. It would also be better to catch only a very specific exception inside the for loop (the one that is thrown due to the transient error). You don't want to retry on an `ArgumentException` for instance.

Comment: but how i throw away the last exception? that's important

Answer (score 3):

You could also try the following:

```
Dim retryCount as Integer = 0
Dim wasSuccessful as Boolean = False

Do
    Try
        <statements>
        'set wasSuccessful if everything was okay.'
        wasSuccessful = True
    Catch
        retryCount +=1
    End Try
Loop Until wasSuccessful = True OrElse retryCount >=5

'check if the statements were unsuccessful'
If Not wasSuccessful Then
    <do something>
End If
```

It will retry up to five times if the statements were not successful but will immediately exit the loop if the statements' execution was successful.

Comment: Now if you do this statement along with catching the specific exception at: `Catch ex as SpecificExceptionType : retryCount += 1 : End Try`
I like this solution, it seems a bit more elegant than a recursive retry or `GoTo` block.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `For` loop or a `While` loop rather than `GoTo`, breaking on success. But other than that, it's the right approach.

Comment: @Job Skeet: It woulb be nice if .NET languages had such constructs.

Comment: Sorry but i dont see how this can be done. The loop would enclose the whole Try ?

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually it's the right approach, although I would not catch each and every exception, see answer by @0xA3.

You could make it a bit 'prettier' by separating the retry logic from the actual code, e.g.:

```
    Sub TryExecute(Of T As Exception)(ByVal nofTries As Integer, 
                                      ByVal anAction As Action)
        For i As Integer = 1 To nofTries - 1
            Try
                anAction()
                Return
            Catch ex As T
                Thread.Sleep(2000)
            End Try
        Next
        ' try one more time, throw if it fails
        anAction()
    End Sub
```

Which could then be used like so:

```
TryExecute(Of SomeExceptionType)(3, Sub()
                                      <Block>
                                    End Sub())
```

This will only work in VB 10, if you're using .Net 3.5 / VB 9, you need to separate this in a separate function

Comment: AFAIK you can't do  Sub()<Block>End Sub() in VB.NET 3.5 or can you?

Comment: @dr. evil That's right, as written the code will only work in VB.Net 10 (.Net 4)

Comment: Oh I see, haven't touch VB.NET 10 yet. It's good to see finally VB got anon delegates as well.

Answer (score 1):

In general, retrying something that failed should be considered very carefully. Usually it is much better to report the error and let the user decide.

Raymond Chen gives a nice example how automatic retries might lead to unwanted problems and gives the advice to avoid retrying:

> **[Take it easy on the automatic retries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/07/489807.aspx)**

Comment: I agree. It's less of a problem if you catch more specific exception types though.